# Dialog wdDialogFileOpen does not always immediately update ActiveDocument

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am posting this for the possible benefit of anyone else who experiences the same problem, but would appreciate any other comments people may have.

The following code has been running without problem for many years:

```
If Dialogs(wdDialogFileOpen).show <> -1 Then
    GoTo ImportTablesEnd
Else
    Set sourceDoc = ActiveDocument
    ....
End If
```

The intention is that, running this code in **DocumentA**, say, the user is prompted to open a file (call it **DocumentB**) which is used later in the code. **DocumentB** is accessed by the variable `sourceDoc`.

I have recently been exercising this code a lot as I test a new version of my product, and I found that the code now fails intermittently, insofar as `sourceDoc` ends up pointing to **DocumentA** rather than **DocumentB**.

It seems that `ActiveDocument` is not always being set immediately on return from `wdDialogFileOpen`. This might be because of recent Office 365 maintenance - I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I have circumvented the problem like this:

```
   Set fileDialog = Dialogs(wdDialogFileOpen)
   If fileDialog.show <> -1 Then
       GoTo ImportTablesEnd
   Else
       Set sourceDoc = Documents(replace(fileDialog.Name, Chr(34), "")) 
       ...
```

The reason for replacing `chr(34)` with an empty string is that `fileDialog.Name` surrounds a chosen file name with quotes if it includes any spaces. Without the replace, simply using `Documents(fileDialog.Name)` results in `Run-time error 4160 "Bad file name"` if a user chooses a file whose name contains spaces.